# Com+ Interop registration with Inno Setup

Tags: .net, inno-setup, com+, dllregistration

I use Inno Setup for creating my setup. All works fine, but I run into the problem: how to register the .NET DLL to make it accessable by COM+. As we all know .NET brings `RegSvcs.exe` for that so I checked the Inno Setup documentation and only found gacinstall which is for Assembly registration, but not use for COM+ interactions.
So I added this in the `[Run]` section

```
; register .Net components for com+
Filename: {win}\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegSvcs.exe; Parameters: "{app}\bin\Common.dll"; Description: Component registration; WorkingDir: {app}\bin; StatusMsg: Component registration...; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

But by testing the setup this line is just skipped.
The DLL is copied to the target before in the `[Files]` section and is available.
After setup I can manually run RegSvcs.exe from command line as well without a problem.

Comment: Just a hint (not a solution to your problem), you can use the `{dotnet40}` constant in your file path to get .NET 4.0 path depending on what mode the setup runs (32-bit or 64-bit), or use `{dotnet4032}` to get 32-bit .NET 4.0 path or `{dotnet4064}` for 64-bit. It removes your path hardcoding.

Comment: But what you're describing is strange, from a first look at it I can't see anything wrong (maybe I would remove the `WorkingDir`, but it shouldn't be a problem I think). Anyway what version of Windows are you using, Vista up ? If so, are you running your setup elevated as admin ?

Comment: The target platform are normally win 2008 R2 systems. Setup always runs with admin priviledges.

Comment: I was asking because I'm suspecting your library was registered, but to a different registry node - not under user's root. Maybe you can try to add the `runasoriginaluser` flag to your run entry, but it's still just a guess...

Comment: I run into this issue when my target application popup with an error that said it can't create a object of my dll. So I found out it wasn't registered at all. Same system, same user register the component from cmd-line works. I make some modifications you suggested and try again, stay tuned :)

Comment: Note that by default Inno assumes that applications are 32-bit.  .NET applications, however, default to dual 32/64-bit (unless you change their Platform to x86, which is required if they're linking to native code).  If you have pure .NET code and you want it to be available to all apps, you should register it twice on 64-bit Windows; once as 32-bit and once as 64-bit.

Comment: Ok, finally after more deep investigations it ends out that inno setup works perfectly. The thing is, that regsvcs.exe registered the component with security interactive user, but it needs local system. @TLama: Add you comment as answer, so I can vote it up. You helped me out trigger the solution...

Comment: So have you finally used the `runasoriginaluser` flag ? By default is used the `runascurrentuser` flag, which inherits the credentials from the wizard (when the `postinstall` flag is not used), so it is the only possible solution I can think up. If not, feel free to post and accept your own answer (and I will vote it up :-)

Comment: @TLama I wrote it misunderstandable. Sorry. I didn't change anything in the setup. The component gets registered correct. My problem was/is that the COM+ entry has wrong credentials. I have to write some code that use 'COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog' to modify security settings after registration. Default there is "interactive user" and I need "SYSTEM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does it work as intended!

**Problem in my case is:**
RegSvcs.exe install the component with wrong credentials.
It install the COM+ with security `interactive user` but as I call it from a service there is no user, so I need `SYSTEM` as credentials.

**Solution:**
Write a small pice of code that modify the security credentials after registering. I didn't find any option flags to tell regsvcs.exe it directly.
Found a post here http://www.carlosag.net/articles/configure-com-plus how to do it and will now adapt the ideas from there to write a small program to do the job.

Comment: +1, maybe you could mention to check the proper registry entries to verify the registering by `RegSvcs.exe` succeeded.

Comment: Well, the COM+ modification will need to init with finding the correct app by CLSID. So if this fails, the component is not registered correct before. But you gave me an idea. My piece of code can then try to register (I know the path of files where to look already) and redo again...

Comment: Ah, now I completely got that. The registration failed due to security settings of your application. Good to know!